# Whether there is any Php client for Oauth2?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

Is there an OAuth consumer library for PHP, that ideally can be used for Google's API?

Comment: google adwords API examples pages, gives you the suggested download url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google offers their own PHP SDK using OAuth2.

Check it out at: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: It should be noted that the source on Google code is a bit dated right now. Take a look at github, there are serveral forks like https://github.com/quizlet/oauth2-php which continue the development at a higher pace. They even got limited support for newer drafts like draft 16, 18 and 20. They also refactored a lot of code so that programming against this library is a bit easier.

Comment: Since DASKAjA posted the Google Code library has been updated. So check it out for yourself if you want to see the current status.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: https://github.com/vznet/oauth_2.0_client_php. It claims it uses the draft 10 of the current OAuth 2.0 specification.

Answer (score 0):

By checking github a bit we found this one:
https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2